# Ubuntu Firefox windows seizing

Tags: firefox, window, tabs

Machine: Dell Inspiron 5567
CPU: Intel i7200U @ 2.5 GHz
RAM: 16 GB
Virtual RAM: 12.6 GB
Monitor (External): 1920 pixels x 1080 pixels
GPU1: Intel Integrated HD 620 @ 33 MHz
GPU2: AMD Radeon R7 M445 with 4 GB @ 920 MHz
Renderer: ICELAND (iceland, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.47, 5.19.0-32-generic)
Version: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.1.6 - kisak-mesa PPA

[Other AMD Radeon GPU Details](https://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-Radeon-R7-M445-Gaming-Benchmarks-and-Specs.195642.0.html)

Usually this problem starts when I have 5 or more Firefox window tabs open at the same time. Basically I switch to one of the newer tabs and then I can't easily switch back. Usually it just delays and delays. Then I hit the super key (or Windows key) twice and I get to the tab I want, but lately it has happened when only two Firefox tabs are open at the same time.

1. This is a new thing to me. Maybe it's an Ubuntu 22.04 issue as we now have Wayland rather than X-windows.
2. How do I deal with this issue?